# Crazy things with PHP sessions (session variables are assigned by refrence when not requested)

Tags: php, session, reference

I have a very strange problem. Here is my script:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['test'] = '123';
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo "<br />\n";

$test = $_SESSION['test'];
var_dump($test);
echo "<br />\n";

$_SESSION['test'] = '1234';
var_dump($test);
```

I'm running this script on 5.3.5 and getting the following output:

```
array(1) { ["test"]=> &string(3) "123" }
string(3) "123"
string(4) "1234"
```

Note that 'test' session variable is stored as reference to "123" string `["test"]=> &string(3) "123"`. ??? Why is that?

And then assigning a new value to session variable, `$test` is changed as well. So `$test` variable is behaving like being a reference to `$_SESSION['test']`. I didn't request this at all.

When running the same script on PHP 5.5.1 everything works correctly. Is my PHP installation broken? Anybody has a clue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In PHP, why are my session variables persisted as references?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765483/in-php-why-are-my-session-variables-persisted-as-references)

Comment: Doesn't assign by reference for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/l7TBnR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need disable  register globals in `php.ini`. Change to:

```
register_globals = Off
```

In 5.5 it works correctly because feature of using register globals removed since PHP 5.4.0. And interpreter ignores your `register_globals = On`. See more about this behavior in  example #2 here http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php.

Comment: You are 100% right! I had register_globals = On
Took me time to find where it was turned on though.
php.ini had it off. It was one of .htaccess files which turned it on.
Thanks!