# $_SESSION linking to variable reference across pages?

Tags: php, session, session-variables, pass-by-reference

I have a PHP session on my website that I am using to store login info. The basic structure of the array is this:

```
$_SESSION = Array(

    [uid]=>Int
    [acc]=>Array
    [lastAction]=>Timestamp

)
```

When I set these session variables in my login PHP script, I set them like this:

```
$_SESSION["uid"] = $uid;
$_SESSION["acc"] = array(...);
$_SESSION["lastAction"] = time();
```

This never posed a problem until I got to one script later on where I went to bind some variables using MySQLi. I wanted to retrieve the `uid` variable from one of my tables, so I went ahead and did this:

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT `uid` ... FROM ...");
...
$stmt->bind_result($uid, ...);
```

The statement ran with no problems and the data is all correct but there's a problem with the session now.

Apparently, `$_SESSION["uid"]` is still tied to the reference `$uid`, even though I'm now on a different page and I didn't pass the variable by reference when setting the session.

---

To test this theory, I went ahead and set my session again and ran this code:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $uid = 1823479;
    print_r($_SESSION);

?>
```

Sure enough, `$_SESSION["uid"]` equals 1823479.

Is this expected behavior? I've never run into this problem before, but since I didn't set the session using references, in my mind this is not expected behavior.

#### Additional Information:

> PHP Ver: 5.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use phpinfo() to check if register_globals is set to "off". It sounds like it might be set to "on", in which case $_SESSION["uid"] would be the same as $uid.

[In PHP, why are my session variables persisted as references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765483/in-php-why-are-my-session-variables-persisted-as-references)
http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/759731-register_globals-off-session-side-effect

Comment: Ah. It is on. I find that rather silly, though. If I made PHP... ;)

Comment: It's a rather big security issue. It was set to "off" by default in PHP 4.2.0, so whoever configured your server must have enabled it manually. The workaround is to disable it if you can (highly recommended), or use a variable with another name.

Comment: Great! Thanks for reporting back!